# Neo4j driver with transaction timeout: how to detect the timeout event?

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm looking at recent versions of the Neo4j driver, which have a nice feature about [transaction timeouts](https://medium.com/neo4j/new-features-in-1-7-neo4j-drivers-4bde893b1374), ie, you can make a query to stop if it cannot return a result within a time constraint.

I don't have clear how the occurrence of such a time out event can be detected and recovered (in my case, I have a number of queries to collect potentially relevant data and I can afford to omit results from too slow queries). Is there a specific exception that is thrown? Or is there some other mechanism?